# Eclipse failing to install Android app on Samsung Galaxy Y

Tags: android, eclipse

Hello Android Enthusiasts,

I am in a funny situation which, it seems, I am stuck in. I have been developing simple Android apps on Eclipse and running on the emulator just fine. But recently my attempt to install and run them on a real device (Samsung Galaxy Y) failed again and again.

I stopped the emulator and plugged my real device to the computer with a USB cable. As soon as I did that, I would see the "Installing device driver software" notification and it would complain that the driver for the Abstract Control Model, ACM, was missing.

A few times I ignored the notification and tried to launch an app on my phone. But Eclipse would simply ignore my read device, start the emulator, and run the app on it instead.

I know it is not an Eclipse issue. But how do I get around this USB issue which seems a common problem on Samsung devices based on comments left by many on various sites?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install the appropriate USB driver for your android device Go through this link first [Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and [Installing a USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Shiv. It works now. I visited the links you provided and read pages. The thing I needed to do came down to the matter of installing the Samsung Kies software. I do not need to use the software itself but the advantage of installing on a computer is that it automatically installs device drivers that may include the ones missing on your computer. So, after having installed Kies, I plugged my Samsung phone to my laptop with a USB cable and this time there was no complaint about missing drivers. My simple app was installed on my Samsung phone. Thanks, again!